# Configure mercurial to merge obvious changes before displaying merge conflicts

Tags: merge, mercurial

I recently ran into a situation where numerous changes were made to the same file on two separate branches, but only a few of these changes result in merge conflicts. However mercurial still requires me to manually merge the entire file for some reason.

A simplified scenario is illustrated in the screenshot:
[image: merge]
Here we have a line being removed in the current branch, a line modified in both branches, and a line added in the other branch. Instead of prompting me to resolve just the merge conflict in the second line, I have to manually merge all 3 lines. There's got to be a better way right?

Using the mercurial internal merge tools gets me close to what I want, but it's definitely not scalable for larger files being merged in the real world.

```
 1 Anchor
 2 Anchor
 3 <<<<<<< local
 4 Line modified by other branch
 5 =======
 6 Line modified by this branch
 7 >>>>>>> other
 8 Anchor
 9 Line added by other branch
10
```

Does anyone know how to configure any merge tool for mercurial that would pre-merge the non-conflicting lines?

Comment: Read http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're getting at. I don't see anything in that document that would help answer my question.